# Fixing neo4j consistency errors

Tags: neo4j, database-backups

After upgrading to 2.1.6 we started noticing the following error during the consistency checks of a full backup:

```
This node record has a label that is not found in the label scan store entry for this node
```

Is there any way to rebuild the label scan store?

Similarly, is there a way to fix these index errors:

```
ERROR: This node was not found in the expected index.
```

Unfortunately going to a previous backup is not an option since we need the new data and cannot recreate it.

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation to why this issue occurs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/jexp/store-utils to copy over the datastore. The tools reads from a source datastore and writes it's data to a new datastore. Not 100%, but I'm pretty confident that this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could shut down the db, delete the label index /schema/label/ so that when you start again the label index will be rebuilt.